# Convergence of the series $f(a_n)a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a monoton function in $[−r, r]$ for some $r>0$. Prove that the if $$\sum a_n$$ converge absolutely then $$\sum f(a_n)a_n$$ converges absolutely
I have not idea how to approach this, but i attempted to prove that $$\sum f(a_n)a_n<\sum a_n$$ but i think think it's not so true.
It's a good idea split it by the formula of summation by parts?
I'am looking for some hint

Comment: Idea: What do you know $a_n$ converges to given that initial series converges? What does that tell you about $f(a_n)$ for sufficiently large n? Hint: Improved comparison test + bound f. (By improved comparison test I mean using the comparison test for n>N: Unsure if this commonly known as the name but was taught it using that name.)

Comment: Maybe i can say this: $f(a_n)$ is monotone, so in one case we have $f(a_n)<f(r)=M$ for some r. So $\sum f(a_n)a_n<M\sum (a_n)$. We conclude this is absolutely convergent
If is weakly decreasing we have $f(a_n)\leq f(-r)=N$, and we conclude like above. It's correst? @J.Dmaths

Comment: I'll write you an answer below: The ideas are almost there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\sum a_n $ absolutely converges. So $a_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Then , by definition :

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} :n>N\implies|a_n|<\epsilon$$

So choose $\epsilon:=r >0$

So $n>N\implies a_n\in(-r,r)$

Given $f(x)$ monotone for $x \in [-r,r]$ that implies that :
$$f(r)\ge f(x) \ge f(-r)$$
Or:
$$ f(r) \le f(x) \le f(-r)$$
for all $x\in [-r,r]$, so certainly holds true for $x\in(-r,r)$.

Take $M:=max(|f(r)|,|f(-r)|)$, so $M\ge 0$.

Then for either case: $$0\le|f(x)|\le M ,\forall x\in (-r,r)$$

So $n>N \implies a_n\in (-r,r)\implies |f(a_n)|\le M$

So consider the inequality below.

$$n>N \implies 0\le |a_n||f(a_n)| \le M|a_n| $$

But clearly as $\sum a_n $ absolutely converges, $M\sum |a_n| = \sum M|a_n|$ also converges.

So by the improved comparison test: $\sum|a_n||f(a_n)| $ converges, so $\sum f(a_n)a_n$ converges absolutely.